# How to sort a file by a 3rd column by using refernce in PERL

Tags: perl

Hello guys so i have to sort a file about 10k lines i wrote this code but it take a lot of time to finish i asked someone and he told to use reference it wont take that much of time but i cant figured out where to use them this is what i did in perl :

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open( IN, "dico_corpus.dic" ) or die "$!";
my @tab;
my $i;
my @tabs;
my $c;
my @tabs2;
$i   = 0;
$c   = 0;
@tab = <IN>;
#here i will read line buy line and put the 3rd colmun(which i want to sort in tabs2)
for ( $i = 0; $i < $#tab; $i++ ) {
    @tabs = split( /\s+/, $tab[$i] );

    $tabs2[$c] = $tabs[2];

    $c++;

}// here tabs2 contain the 3rd colmun to sort


@tabs2 = sort(@tabs2);

open( OUT, ">>resultat.txt" );# to print result by adding line by line to resultat.txt

foreach my $word (@tabs2) {# here i will take the first value in tabs2
                           # and get the first line from the original file
                           # and test the 3rd colmun if its the same so i 
                           # print the whole line if its not so to the next  
                           #line 

    foreach my $var (@tab) {
        @tabs = split( /\s+/, $var );

        if ( $word eq $tabs[2] ) {
            my $ligne = join( "\t", $tabs[1], $tabs[0], $tabs[2] );
            print OUT $ligne, "\n";
        }
    }
}

close(IN);
close(OUT);
```

> some lines from the original file
>
> 3851  4178    de
>
> 1972  6643    la
>
> 1391   2246    à
>
> 1098  5163    et
>
> 656    8429    que

Comment: Please use punctuation marks between your sentences so we know where we can take a breath.

Comment: how is that guys its my first time posting here ? i will add comments to my code just a sec

Comment: Could you please show a few lines (3-5) of your input file and the expected output for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the Schwartzian transform (ST) @toto refers to can be used here. But I presume it may seem a bit obscure to you and I'd like to show a more explicit solution. This will be slower than the ST but might be easier to read for beginners.

The first block simply reads the complete input file into the array `@lines`. I used the recommended 3-parameter-open. See Perl's [tutorial on open](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html) for details.

Perl has a built-in [sort function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) which sorts a list (or array) lexicographically (i.e. `('c', 'a', 'b') → ('a', 'b', 'c')`). If that doesn't suit your needs you can also supply a *custom comparison function* like I did here with `by_third_column`. This function gets called with the magic parameters `$a` and `$b`. These are the items that will be compared. In your case `$a` and `$b` are some (arbitrary) complete lines of your input and the function has to decide which line is "greater".

So the function `by_third_column` splits the two given lines at whitespace apart and picks the 3rd items ("fields") of these lines. This is the `my $a3 = …` and `my $b3 = …` part. Then these 3rd fields are lexicographically compared (`$a3 cmp $b3`).

Finally we call `sort` on the `@lines` array but supply that custom compare function. The last block simply outputs (appends) the sorted output to the file 'resultat.txt'.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open( my $in, '<', 'dico_corpus.dic' ) or die "$!";
my @lines = <$in>;
close($in);

sub by_third_column
{
    my $a3 = ( split /\s+/, $a )[2];
    my $b3 = ( split /\s+/, $b )[2];
    return $a3 cmp $b3;
}

my @sorted = sort by_third_column @lines;

open( my $out, '>>', 'resultat.txt' ) or die "$!";
print $out @sorted;
close($out);
```

---

**Update** The comments to @toto's and my answer made me curious so I did a [`Benchmark`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark.html). I encapsulated the original code, toto's Schwartzian Transform, and my suggestion with the custom comparison function in three subroutines. I setup an input array with 10_000 lines of three 10-letter-random words each:

```
vfkyscicki nqqnfpjylf kevurxexov
bqordmljgh nrypcmvids tvsxsqhizl
uequmgbhbg bnfdyxgcpo krwnjfuhpe
...
```

The benchmark was measured with

```
my $speed = Benchmark::timethese(
    -250,
    {
        Custom   => \&custom,
        ST       => \&ST,
        Original => \&original,
    }
);
Benchmark::cmpthese($speed);
```

I had to use that much CPU secs because the performance difference between ST/Custom and Original is so huge that I always got "warning: too few iterations for a reliable count". The results were

```
Benchmark: running Custom, Original, ST for at least 250 CPU seconds...
    Custom: 269 wallclock secs (268.76 usr +  0.00 sys = 268.76 CPU) @  9.86/s (n=2651)
  Original: 253 wallclock secs (252.18 usr +  0.00 sys = 252.18 CPU) @  0.02/s (n=4)
        ST: 272 wallclock secs (271.72 usr +  0.00 sys = 271.72 CPU) @ 32.82/s (n=8918)

               Rate Original   Custom       ST
Original 1.59e-02/s       --    -100%    -100%
Custom       9.86/s   62086%       --     -70%
ST           32.8/s  206817%     233%       --
```

As you can see, Schwartzian Transform: *"douze points"*. It's about 3-4 times faster than the custom compare function which in turn is approximatly 600 times faster than the original approach for 10_000 inputlines.

So ST ***is*** faster (I didn't doubt that) than a custom compare function but the *real* improvement was not to iterate n² times over the input.

Comment: @ZoCode You're welcome. I just saw you also swap the columns on output which my suggestion does not. Can I leave that as an excercise?

Comment: but if i have a number in the third column i dont think it will work with cmp i tried it is there any think to make it work with numbers also ?

Comment: @ZoCode Yes, replace `cmp` with `<=>`. Looks funny, but `<=>` is for comparing numbers. So `return $a3 <=> $b3;` will do.

Comment: i know yes but the problem if i have like "a" in the 3rd colmun and in the other line there is 5 in the 3rd comlunthe result wont be correct

Comment: Well now it depends on what you consider _"correct"_. Is `5` greater than `a` or lesser? For mixed values use `cmp` and numbers will come first. With `<=>` the columns will be _interpreted_ as numbers and everything _not_ starting with a number will be interpreted as 0 (zero).

Comment: i got it now sorry for asking a lot of questions and thank you , :) u r the best

Comment: LOL. Tell that to my boss.

Comment: This code is slow because of `split` for each comparison. Notice @Toto answer.

Comment: @EugenKonkov Sure. I got curious and benchmarked. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Schartzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Data::Dumper;
use Modern::Perl;


chomp (my @lines = <DATA>);

my @sorted = 
    map {$_->[0]}
    sort {$a->[1] cmp $b->[1]}
    map { my $third = (split/\s+/,$_)[2]; [$_, $third] }
        @lines;

say Dumper\@sorted;


__DATA__
3851 4178 de
1972 6643 la
1391 2246 à
1098 5163 et
656 8429 que
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          '3851 4178 de',
          '1098 5163 et',
          '1972 6643 la',
          '656 8429 que',
          '1391 2246 à'
        ];
```

Comment: @zocode: FYI Schartzian Transform is really much more efficient than a simple sort.

Comment: I perfectly agree (+1) and would prefer it to my solution (esp. when speed matters) but it is also a decision between readability and performance. For beginners the ST might look like … _"Umm, what?"_ because the `map` thing is not the easiest. And the ST has two of them ;-)

Comment: @PerlDog If `map` is hard one should consider another career.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is slow is that the nested foreach loops are giving you a 10K x 10K inner loop. Your friend is telling you to use a hash with the `tabs2` value as the key and the record as the value (`$myhash{$tabs[2]}=$tab[$i]`). Then you do a single loop over a `sort keys %myhash` and print `$myhash{$thekey}`.

Comment: thank u Jeff i got it , there is no way here to use reference  \ ?

Comment: @ZoCode Actually, yes. You could use a reference to `$tab[$i]` instead of a copy (as the hash value). (Dereference on the print.) But that is not why the original code was slow.